# Is "zed" a valid name for $\emptyset$?

Tags: notation, terminology

I've always known that $\emptyset$ is called an *empty set* or *null*, until recently, when I heard someone calling it *zed*.  I looked it everywhere but couldn't find this naming.

Is "*zed*" a valid name for the $\emptyset$ symbol?

Comment: Zed's dead baby, Zed's dead.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Best comment I've read in months.

Comment: No. It's not a valid name for the empty set.

Comment: Zod. All kneel before the power of Zod: $\{\varnothing\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I have never heard it called that (of course, it is always possible that some in subfield of mathematics I'm not familiar with, it is an accepted name).  However, non-Americans will usually call $\mathbb{Z}$ (the integers) "zed", perhaps you misunderstood?

Comment: Misunderstood? No. But I strongly believe that the person doesn't know the actual meaning of $\emptyset$.

Comment: Then I think it'd probably be best to just ignore what they call it :)

Comment: "First of all - it's YY-Zed". :)

Comment: @rschwieb: I actually find that quite surprising. You don't say `ahr ehn` for the expression $\mathbb{R}^n$, or `cee adjoin x` for $\mathbb{C}[x]$?

Comment: @ZevChonoles Ah, when you add powers I have to take back what I said :)  When I read it just now, I was thinking I never heard someone say "let $x\in\Bbb Z$ as "let $x$ be in zee/zed". I use "adjoin" when talking about field extensions, but not for polynomials...

Comment: @rschwieb: Still, I think > 90% of the time I would say `let x be in zee`, and this is true of any of my professors and peers I can remember.

Comment: @ZevChonoles All I can say is "I experienced exactly the opposite." Do they say "pee ex" for the powerset of $X$? I know I definitely made a point of using "let x be an integer" to pronounce $x\in \Bbb Z$ rather than "let x be in zee" because I thought reciting the letters would be counterproductive for beginners not fluent in the notation.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, there are two similar symbols:

U+00D8 Ø latin capital letter o with stroke

U+2205 ∅ empty set

The first is a letter used in Danish, Norwegian, and Faroese languages. The second is the empty set symbol. The rendering of "\emptyset" on this site looks like the first, and ought to look like the second, in my opinion.

Now, after that diversion, back to your question ... English people use "zed" to refer to the last letter of the alphabet (the thing that Americans call "zee") regardless of whether they are talking about the set of integers or not.

I have lived in both England and the US for decades, and never heard anyone use "zed" to refer to the empty set in either country.